# Ubuntu16.04 LTS: failed to download package files. Check your internet connection

Tags: networking, apt

I realize this question has been asked multiple times and I've browsed through the answers and tried out the suggestions in them as good as I could. Still, the problem remains.

Since some replies to the question suggest to copy&paste the result of `sudo apt-get update`, I add it here, with the links it lists deleted since my reputation isn't good enough to be allowed posting more than two of those.

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid InRelease
Hit:2
Hit:3
Hit:4
Hit:5
Ign:6
Hit:7
Hit:8
Hit:9
Reading package lists... Done                      
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-i386.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-i386.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list:4 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list:4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can copy and paste the output as text and format it accordingly. Please do not post pictures of things that can otherwise be written as text.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought of doing that, but I've got no idea what info is useful, and what can be omitted.

Comment: Go ahead and post what you think may be useful. Having some information is better than no information when it comes to helping people.

Comment: all right ... here it comes:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and do the following to fix your sources lists problem:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick-partner.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lucid-partner.list
```

This will remove those old files which cause you an error, and probably did already cause you an error before you updated.

You might as well make sure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains proper links too. Below i post you a version of the 16.04 LTS sources list which has all package sources enabled. Just do `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and replace the content with the following block:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

You can delete the content of the file quickly when you place the cursor on the first line start and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> until all lines are gone, then you copy the block here and paste it into the file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. I simply condensed the whole file into a few lines so it would not take a lot of space here. Other thing you can do is, checking if the lines which contain `http` in the `sources.list` all mentioning `xenial` as version word.

After you done that, end your editing by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, press <kbd>y</kbd> to save and <kbd>return</kbd> to confirm the file name.

After that run a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and then use simply the GUI tools provided to change the repositories you want to have switched on.

Comment: Al right... beginning now...

Comment: So the rm part worked fine. the sources list that is currently present holds a lot of warning lines  about being entirely unsupported and similar. Although I can see at the bottom the '^\ Replace' thingy, I've got no idea as to how to proceed replacing the existing block for the one you provided ...?

Comment: O.k., those warning lines in there are comment lines, you can delete the content of the file quickly when you place the cursor on the first lines start and press ctrl+k until all lines are gone, then you copy the block here and paste it into the file with ctrl+shift+v. I simply condensed the whole file into a few lines so it would not take a lot of space here. Other thing you can do is checking if the  `http` lines in the `sources.list` all containing xenial as version word.

Comment: Swell! It all worked, except at the end I get following message:E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Just run the Apt-get update one time more, this should fix it. If my answer was solving your problem and helped you you can accept it by clicking the check-mark beside it and/or up-vote it.

Comment: I will gladly rate you, for you have already guided me through a big chunk of the problem. Still, having ran the apt-get update a second time, I get the following as response:

Comment: Err:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable/main i386 google-earth-stable i386 6.1.0.4738-r0
  404  Not Found [IP: 74.125.136.93 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb/pool/main/g/google-earth-stable/google-earth-stable_6.1.0.4738-r0_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 74.125.136.93 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Ah o.k., look in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for a `google` called `.list` file and copy it out of that directory  and delete it in the directory or move it out of this directory. seems that this file isn't valid as well anymore and you must make a new one. Google is your friend for finding solutions how this file should look like on 16.04.

Comment: Seems to work as should now. Thanks for helping me out!